# Bad request with base64 encoded parameter in WCF rest url on IIS 7

Tags: wcf, rest, iis-7.5, base64

I have a rest wcf 4.0 service that takes in a base64 encoded string as a parameter. It works properly when I run the service in Visual Studio using casini, but gives an Error 400 message when I run the same service under IIS 7.5. The break point doesn't get hit. I guess its not a problem with the code because it works under casini with the same code and web.config.

What changes do I need to make to enable the service to function under IIS 7.5?

This is the URL

```
http://localhost/MyServices/MyServ.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
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show an example of such a problematic URL. And do you have more error details? Do you get "Illegal characters in path."?

Comment: updated the question with the actual url. When I run this url all I get on IE is 

The webpage cannot be found

 HTTP 400

Answer (score 2):

The equal sign has a special meaning in the URL. It separates a parameter key from its value. The way you use the trailing equal signs, IIS will reject it.

Note that the Base 64 encoding uses additional characters that have a special meaning in a URL and cause problems (namely `+` and `/`). Therefore I recommend to use a modified Base 64 encoding that uses only URL safe characters.

Typically, the following characters are replaced:

`+` with `-`,
`/` with `_`, and
`=` with `*`.

**Update:**

The Javascript code you use for Base 64 encoding is easy to modify. Just replace this line:

```
var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
```

with

```
var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_*";
```

And

```
return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
```

with:

```
return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '***'.slice(r || 3);
```

**Update 2:**

I'm afraid the Base 64 URLs are never going to work with IIS. IIS still treats every part of an URL as a file or directory name. There are many problems with this implementation (just try COM2 or PRN as a URL segment).

You'll need to come up with a different URL scheme or request type. Either use a POST request to transmit the Base64 encoded part or use a URL like:

```
http://server/MyServices/MyServ.svc/Accept?data=eyJXb3JkY291bnQiOjMwLCJ...VsbH1dfQ**
```

But the second case will only work if the URL isn't too long. It wouldn't expect URLs of more than 1000 characters to work.

Comment: I removed the == sign and tried it. did not help. How do I use a modified base 64 encoding? the one I used is from the Javascript method on this link http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/

Comment: Does any of your WFC URLs work on IIS? If not, the setup of your WFC service might be wrong or incomplete. Start testing with the simplest service URL.

Comment: Yes the same url works if I reduce the length of the base64 encoded string. However, that makes it an invalid base64 string

Comment: I tried increasing the length of the URL, query string, max allowed content to 20480000 using the request filtering option under IIS and that still did not work

Comment: @user20358: See my update for how to modify the Javascript Base64 encoding. You'll need to do a similar thing on the .NET side or use `String.Replace` to undo the modification.

Comment: actually this service will be called from an html page that uses javascript to get data from this service. I modified the javascript and I still get the same error. The base64 string generated now with the new b64 key still has the == at the end of the statement.

Comment: @user20358: I'm afraid your URL has a length problem as well. See my update.

Comment: 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

Comment: @user20358: There's a second line in Javascript that needs to be fixed. See my update. But honestly: you could have figured that out yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I did not think the base64 encoding could be a problem. I removed the special characters manually from the string and tried it on the service and it did not work.Regarding the url length, is there a setting besides the one I tried to increase the input capacity? Or is changing the service method from get to post the only way to go?

Comment: @user20358: A POST request gives you an almost unlimited length for Base64 encoded data. If you can turn the Base64 into a query parameter (`?data=xxxxx`), then you can probably go up to 1000 characters (about 750 bytes of unencoded data). But that's it. I don't know of any other way to tweak it.

Comment: @user20358: I've decoded your sample URL and seen that the Base 64 encoded part contains JSON data. It would be far more natural, to use a POST request to send a JSON document and to get rid of the Base 64 encoding. I can't see any purpose for it. But it makes things more complicated.

Comment: sending JSON data gave me an error 400 bad request due to invalid charachters. Urlencoding them did not help too. Plus if I send it via a query string after the ? sign there is a limit to number of charachters I can send across. base64 seemed the only way to go..